# How to find all submodules of a given $\Bbb R[x]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In class my professor gave an example where $M$ is the $\mathbb R[x]$-module given by $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ with $x$-action given by

$$A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
He then went on to show how for submodules $L$ and $P$ of $M$,

$$M \cong L \oplus P$$ 
where $L$ is the line through $(1,1,1),(0,0,0)$ $\in \mathbb{R^{3}}$ and

$$P = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R^{3}}|a+b+c=0\}$$

I understand $L$ is just an eigenvector from $A$, but I'm not sure how he figured out $P$ to make $M$ the direct sum of $L$ and $P$.

Comment: $P$ is the orthogonal complement of $L$, isn't it? I guess you still have to show that it's stable under $A$.

Comment: $P$ is the "usual" complement of $L$; so I guess here your teacher just intuited that it might be $P$ and then proved it was stable (by usual I simply that if often pops up, even in contexts where there's no orthogonality involved)

Comment: @André3000 I think you should expand a little bit on your comment and write it down as an answer. As this is unanswered but the comments are more than good hints.